# Python squares and lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def index_power(array, n):
    if n &lt; len(array):
       return (array)[n]**n
    else:
       return -1


if __name__ == '__main__':
#These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
assert index_power([1, 2, 3, 4], 2) == 9, "Square"
assert index_power([1, 3, 10, 100], 3) == 1000000, "Cube"
assert index_power([0, 1], 0) == 1, "Zero power"
assert index_power([1, 2], 3) == -1, "IndexError"
```

OK I got syntax error on line 2

Here is the following what I need to do here:
 You are given an array with positive numbers and a number N. You should find the N-th power of the element in the array with the index N. If N is outside of the array, then return -1. Don't forget that the first element has the index 0.

Comment: `n &lt; len(array)` --->  Not python buddy ... :(  Looks like C

Comment: so how u would do it in python?

Comment: OP seems to have copied it from somewhere and it's converted `<` to `&lt;`.

Comment: `&lt` is an HTML "less than" (or more commonly known: `<`). Stray `&lt` ad `&gt` are common in text people copy off the internet. This is an easy **should fail** sign to any tester looking at their code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` statement should instead read

```
if n < len(array):
   return (array)[n]**n
```

Again here, You can ignore the brackets around array and return `array[n] ** n`.

The indices of the array must be within *-length to length-1*. However in your case it is better to restrict it to positive indices. Python has a very good way of doing this. Your codition can be changed to `0<= n < len(array)`. So the final function will look something like

```
def index_power(array, n):
   if 0<= n < len(array):
      return array[n]**n
   else:
      return -1
```

Comment: can i ask u something?

Comment: @Naeie If related to the question, then OK

Comment: You are given an array of integers. You should find the sum of the elements with even indexes (0th, 2nd, 4th...) then multiply this summed number and the final element of the array together. Don't forget that the first element has an index of 0.               
For an empty array, the result will always be 0 (zero).

Comment: @Naeie That is an un-related question. Do ask a separate question.  Someone will surely help. :) .

Answer (score 1):

That "& lt;" should be replaced with a < symbol. This is the only error you have.

**It looks like you copied and pasted this code from somewhere**; please try to understand what your code is doing and whether each expression in it is valid before appealing for help.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def homework(list, n):
...     try:
...             i = list[n]
...             return pow(i, n)
...     except IndexError:
...             return -1
...
>>> homework([1,2,3,4],2)
```

Tada?